# gradle submodules of submodules not built with :submodule:build syntax

Tags: gradle

I have the following project structure correctly found by gradle:

```
$ ./gradlew projects
Root project 'test-project'
\--- Project ':sub-1'
     \--- Project ':sub-1:sub-2'
```

Which makes me believe that my setups is correct.

Now, I have found that the following gradle syntax:

```
$ ./gradlew clean :sub-1:build
```

is not equivalent to:

```
$ cd sub-1
$ ../gradlew clean build
$ cd ..
```

The above is equivalence is stated in many places on the gradle website.
Like [HERE](https://guides.gradle.org/creating-multi-project-builds/)

Running the former, the result is incorrect:

```
> Task :sub-1:test
test.project.LibrarySuite > someLibraryMethod is always true PASSED
```

Running the latter, the result is correct:

```
> Task :sub-1:test
test.project.LibrarySuite > someLibraryMethod is always true PASSED
> Task :sub-1:sub-2:test
test.project.LibrarySuite > someLibraryMethod is always true PASSED
```

Please help me understand if I might have assumed or done anything wrong, or if it's a bug that should be raised to the gradle team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find detailed description of how Gradle handles execution of tasks in a multiproject build setup here : https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/intro_multi_project_builds.html#sec:executing_a_multiproject_build , specially:

> From a user’s perspective, multi-project builds are still collections
> of tasks you can run. The difference is that you may want to control
> which project’s tasks get executed. You have two options here:
>
> - Change to the directory corresponding to the subproject you’re
>   interested in and just execute gradle  as normal.
> - Use a qualified task name from any directory, although this is usually
>   done from the root. For example: gradle :services:webservice:build
>   will build the webservice subproject and any subprojects it depends
>   on.
>
> The first approach is similar to the single-project use case, but
> Gradle works slightly differently in the case of a multi-project
> build. The command gradle test will execute the test task in any
> subprojects, relative to the current working directory, that have that
> task. So if you run the command from the root project directory,
> you’ll run test in api, shared, services:shared and
> services:webservice. If you run the command from the services project
> directory, you’ll only execute the task in services:shared and
> services:webservice.

This explains how Gradle behaves in the two examples you gave in your question :

1. `$ ./gradlew clean :sub-1:build`

   from the root project directory:  you execute task `clean`, which will be executed for current project and each subprojects below,  then `:sub-1:build` (with qualified task name) which executes `build` tasks ONLY for subproject `sub1`

Gradle execution log:

```
> Task :clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :sub-1:clean
> Task :sub-1:sub-2:clean UP-TO-DATE
> Task :sub-1:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :sub-1:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :sub-1:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :sub-1:jar
> Task :sub-1:assemble
> Task :sub-1:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :sub-1:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :sub-1:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :sub-1:test NO-SOURCE
> Task :sub-1:check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :sub-1:build
```

**EDIT** to answer @Guido's comment: this will also build any other projects `sub-1` depends on, so `./gradlew clean :sub-1:build` will also trigger build of `sub-2` if `sub-1` project **dependsOn** `sub-2`:

*sub-1 build.gradle*

```
dependencies {
   implementation project(":sub-1:sub-2")
}
```

2. `$ cd sub-1 && ../gradlew clean build`

From `sub-1` subproject directory , you trigger tasks `clean` then `build`, without using qualified names, so these two tasks will both be executed on current project and sub-projects` :

Gralde output:

```
$ ../gradlew  clean build --console=plain
> Task :sub-1:clean
> Task :sub-1:sub-2:clean
> Task :sub-1:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :sub-1:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :sub-1:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :sub-1:jar
> Task :sub-1:assemble
> Task :sub-1:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :sub-1:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :sub-1:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :sub-1:test NO-SOURCE
> Task :sub-1:check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :sub-1:build
> Task :sub-1:sub-2:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :sub-1:sub-2:processResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :sub-1:sub-2:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :sub-1:sub-2:jar
> Task :sub-1:sub-2:assemble
> Task :sub-1:sub-2:compileTestJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :sub-1:sub-2:processTestResources NO-SOURCE
> Task :sub-1:sub-2:testClasses UP-TO-DATE
> Task :sub-1:sub-2:test NO-SOURCE
> Task :sub-1:sub-2:check UP-TO-DATE
> Task :sub-1:sub-2:build
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The past I don't agree/understand is the following:

Comment: @Guido what is the part you did not understand ?

Comment: `gradle :services:webservice:build` **will build the webservice subproject and any subprojects it depends on.** 
 
Doesn't this mean that `gradle :sub-1:build` should build also it's subproject sub-2?

Comment: @Guido be careful, there are two kinds of relations between projects:   parent/subproject relationship (the one described in my answer) which is used to determine tasks to be executed depending on which task you invoke and "from where" you invoke gradle (current directory) ,  and  **Project dependency"** ( see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_dependencies.html#sub:project_dependencies ). So:  `gradle :sub-1:build` will also build `sub-2` *ONLY IF* `sub-1` **dependsOn** `sub-2` (e.g.: `{ implementation project(':sub-1:sub-2') }` in `sub-1` build script)